# How to specify python interpreter on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, cmd

I have both python 3.11.1 and 3.10.9 installed on my windows 10 system with the appropriate PATH variables configured. I can run `python` from the command line to access the latest versions interpreter, but `python3.10.9`, `python3.10` and `python310` all return with a `CommandNotFoundException` error. The documentation have led me to believe that using python `3.10.9` would be the correct way to do that, but it seems like this may only apply to unix based systems.

I've tried running `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236983/how-to-specify-python-interpreter-on-windows) thread but that does not work when attempting to pass an argument (e.g. `venv`) because it treats the second string as path to a file to run with the python executable. `C:\Users\operator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python venv app-venv` returns:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\app\venv': [Errno 2]
> No such file or directory

I am mainly trying to create virtual environments using different python versions, but there may be other reasons I need this in the future.

Comment: This will work if python was installed using defaults. A 2nd program was installed. To run 3.11, open a command prompt and enter `py -3.11`. To run 3.10 enter `py -3.10`. To see if `py.exe` is installed, at the command prompt enter `where py.exe`, the response should be `C:\Windows\py.exe` if it is installed.

Comment: Alternatively you could try `"%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"`, or for the earlier version `"%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"`